# How to get the Interface ID (IID, i.e. the GUID) of an interface when importing a WinRT winmd?

Tags: winapi, com, windows-runtime, midl, winmd

## Short version

How to you get the interface identifier (IID) for an interface from a `*.winmd` file when using **IMetadataImport**?

e.g. **Windows.Globalization.ICalendar**: `{CA30221D-86D9-40FB-A26B-D44EB7CF08EA}`

## Longer Version

A [good example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160622-00/?p=93725) is **Windows.Globalization.ICalendar** interface. Its IID is `CA30221D-86D9-40FB-A26B-D44EB7CF08EA`.

### It's in the IDL

You can find it in the source `Windows.Globalization.idl` file:

```
[exclusiveto(Windows.Globalization.Calendar)]
[uuid(CA30221D-86D9-40FB-A26B-D44EB7CF08EA)]
[version(0x06020000)]
interface ICalendar : IInspectable
{
   //...snip...
}
```

**Reminder**: You're not supposed to parse these files. It gets compiled into a `*.winmd` assembly, and that database is the ground-truth.

### It's in the header

You can find it in the `windows.globalization.h` file, which was generated from the `*.winmd` using an import tool:

```
namespace ABI {
    namespace Windows {
        namespace Globalization {
            
            MIDL_INTERFACE("CA30221D-86D9-40FB-A26B-D44EB7CF08EA")
            ICalendar : public IInspectable
            {
               //...snip...
            }
```

### It's even in the winmd

You can even find the InterfaceID in the resulting compiled `*.winmd` assembly database:

[image]

But how do **I** get it when using the documented `IMetadataImporter` API?

## Code

The [abridged version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54738573/how-to-get-an-enumeration-value-when-using-imetadataimport) of how to get up and running reading `winmd` metadata files:

```
// Create your metadata dispenser:
IMetadataDispsener dispener;
MetaDataGetDispenser(CLSID_CorMetaDataDispenser, IMetaDataDispenser, out dispenser);

//Open the winmd file we want to dump
String filename = "C:\Windows\System32\WinMetadata\Windows.Globalization.winmd";

IMetaDataImport reader; //IMetadataImport2 supports generics
dispenser.OpenScope(filename, ofRead, IMetaDataImport, out reader); //"Import" is used to read metadata. "Emit" is used to write metadata.
```

## Bonus Reading

- MSDN Blogs: [Metadata Unmanaged API](http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/images/Metadata_Umanaged_API.pdf) *(a preliminary PDF version of an old Word document that, as far as i can tell, is the only Microsoft documentation for the Metadata API)* *([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170312154730/http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/images/Metadata_Umanaged_API.pdf))*

Comment: You need to call `GetCustomAttributeByName` to retrieve the value of the `Windows.Foundation.Metadata.GuidAttribute` attribute and then parse the resulting blob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short Version

The custom attribute **blob** is the C# serialized format of a **Guid** class:

> ### 3.2.2 DefineCustomAttribute
>
> The format of *pBlob* for defining a custom attribute is defined in later in this spec. (broadly speaking, the blob records the argument values to the class constructor, together with zero or more values for named fields/properites – in other words, the information needed to instantiate the object specified at the time the metadata was emitted). If the constructor requires no arguments, then there is no need to provide a blob argument.
>
> ### 4.3.6 GetCustomAttributeProps
>
> A custom attribute is stored as a blob whose format is understood by the metadata engine, and by Reflection; essentially a list of argument values to a constructor method which will create an instance of the custom attribute.

In order to get the **GuidAttriute** guid value, you have to emulate C#'s deserializing a **Guid** object from a stream.

## Long Version

Starting with your **IMetadataImport** you call **IMetaDataImport.GetCustomAttributeByName**.

The first tricky part is figuring out the name of the attribute I'm after. I know it's **`Guid`** when viewed in IDL or C#:

```
[Guid("CA30221D-86D9-40FB-A26B-D44EB7CF08EA")]
interface ICalendar
{
    //...
}
```

And that underneath it would actually be called [**`"GuidAttribute"`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2). But neither of those actually work:

- `"Guid"`: Fails with `S_FALSE`
- `"GuidAttribute"`: Fails with `S_FALSE`

You might try the *full* name of the attribute class:

- **`"System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute"`**

But that also fails because that's the name of the **GuidAttribute** class in the .NET framework. In the WinRT library you have to use **`"Windows.Foundation.Metadata.GuidAttribute"`**:

- **`"Guid"`**: Fails with `S_FALSE`
- **`"GuidAttribute"`**: Fails with `S_FALSE`
- **`"System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute"`**: Fails with `S_FALSE` (CLR only)
- **`"Windows.Foundation.Metadata.GuidAttribute"`**: Works

Now that we figured out the *name* of the attribute to find, we can query for it:

```
mdToken calendarTokenID = 0x02000022; //Windows.Globalization.ICalendar
String  attributeName   = "Windows.Foundation.Metadata.GuidAttribute";

Pointer blob;
UInt32 blobLen;
reader.GetCustomAttributeByName(calendarTokenID, attributeName, out blob, out blobLen);
```

The next tricky part is is decoding the blob.

## Decoding the blob

Custom attributes each have a different serialization formats. The blob is essentially passed to the Attribute's constructor. The serialization format is the same as the C# serialization format.

For **GuidAttribute** attributes, the binary serialization format is 20-bytes:

```
01 00                                            Prolog (2-bytes)       0x0001 ==> version 1
1D 22 30 CA D9 86 FB 40 A2 6B D4 4E B7 CF 08 EA  Guid (16-bytes)        "CA30221D-86D9-40FB-A26B-D44EB7CF08EA"
00 00                                            Trailing null (2-bytes)
```

The easiest way for me to extract the Guid is to declare a matching structure, cast the returned pointer to a type of that structure, and access the **Guid** member:

```
struct SerializedGuidAttribute
{
   UInt16 prolog; //2-bytes. 0x0001 
   Guid   guid;   //16-byte guid
   UInt16 footer; //2-byte footer
}
typedef SerializedGuidAttribute* PSerializedGuidAttribute;

Guid guidAttriute = PSerializedGuidAttribute(blob).guid;
```

## And you have it

```
Guid GetGuidAttribute(IMetadataReader reader, mdToken intf)
{
   Pointer blob;
   UInt32 blobLen;
   reader.GetCustomAttributeByName(intf, "Windows.Foundation.Metadata.GuidAttribute", 
         out blob, out blobLen);

   //if (blobLen != 20) { throw new Exception("Something") };

   return PSerializedGuidAttribute(blob).guid;
}
```

## **Bonus**

- Microsoft Metadata API documentation

  - 9/8/2000: [.docx](https://archive.org/download/MetadataAPI/MetadataAPI.docx)
  - 8/2/2001: [.pdf](https://archive.org/download/MetadataUmanagedAPI/Metadata_Umanaged_API.pdf)